# Python program to operate with matrices and vector cross product

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, vector

I have written a python program that, 
given a matrix `a` of 3 vectors `a1`, `a2`, `a3`,  it calculates a matrix `b` of 3 vectors `b1`, `b2`, `b3` in the following way:

[image]

The triple product (in the denominator) is just the determinant.

In order to check if the program is working, this relation has to be satisfied:

[image]

In other words:

`det(b) = 1/det(a)`

In the program I have carefully used `cross` and np `array`. However, it does not satisfy the above relation:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import pi as pi

# 'a' matrix:
a = np.array([[ 0.291761097764E+01 , 0.000000000000E+00 , 0.574463427333E+01  ],
              [ -0.145880548882E+01 , 0.252672522500E+01 , 0.574463427333E+01  ],
              [ -0.145880548882E+01 ,-0.252672522500E+01 , 0.574463427333E+01  ]])

# 'a' vectors:
a_1 = [ 0.291761097764E+01 , 0.000000000000E+00 , 0.574463427333E+01  ]
a_2 = [ -0.145880548882E+01 , 0.252672522500E+01 , 0.574463427333E+01  ]
a_3 = [ -0.145880548882E+01 ,-0.252672522500E+01 , 0.574463427333E+01  ]

# volume of 'a' matrix:
V_a = np.linalg.det(a)
print 'V_a = ', V_a

cte = (2*pi)/V_a

VEC_1 = np.cross(a_2, a_3)
VEC_2 = np.cross(a_3, a_1)
VEC_3 = np.cross(a_1, a_2)

# calculation of 'b' vectors:
b_1 = cte * VEC_1
b_2 = cte * VEC_2
b_3 = cte * VEC_3

print  'b_1 = ',  b_1
print  'b_2 = ',  b_2
print  'b_3 = ',  b_3

# building 'b' matrix:
b = np.vstack ([  b_1 , b_2,  b_3 ])
print 'b = ', b

# volume of 'b' matrix:
V_b = np.linalg.det(b)
print 'V_b = ', V_b
print "1/V_a = ", 1/V_a

print "1/V_a should be equal to V_b; however, we do not get this equality"
```

**EDIT**: The last equation shown is not correct. The following shall be more exact:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should have is `1/V_a=V_b/(8*pi**3)` and not `1/V_a=V_b` (as you ignored the `2*pi` in your last equation in the printscreen), and the former indeed holds when you run the code.

Comment: You are completely right.... See the edit, I have derived the proper equation, so that the (8*pi**3) arises naturally. Let me know if you have some concerns with the derivation, I think that the vector quadruple product rule has to be applied.